# UI Design on Windows Mobile/CE

Tags: windows, mobile

I have recently started on a project developing a window mobile/ce buisiness application.  I have a ui design that uses a wizard to capture input data.  To get the wizard started we open a windows form and maximize it.  The form has one panel on it that is set to the size of the form.  We pass a reference to the panel into the wizard controller as a container for the wizard user controls (each wizard step is a user control and the user control's size is set to that of the panel and thus the windows form.  When viewed in a windows mobile emulator this works great the user control takes up the entire screen and the controls on the wizard step control are all visible on the screen with no vertical or horizontal scroll bars visible.  When we load this onto one of the potential handheld devices the windows form doesn't fit exactly onto the screen as I would expect. There are both horizontal and vertical scroll bars and the controls aren't all visible.  Does anyone have any hints and tips on getting around this problem?  Is it possible to maximize a windows form in such a way that it exactly fills the screen on any mobile or ce device?

Comment: Could you add some paragraph breaks to your posting? It would improve readability for me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the screen resolution of your emulator and of your handheld device.
I suspect you are working on different screen resolutions.
If it's the case, then set the screen res for your emulator to match the screen res of your device. If for some reason this is not possible, just create your form to match the screen res of the device and try to fit all your UI in that limited space.

If you need to support many screen resolutions, you have 2 approaches:
1. Develop for the lowest res. This might look a bit ugly for higher res devices
2. Use anchors and control docking when defining your form layout.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I would have thought that maximizing the form would maximize it to the size of the screen.  My controls should all fit onto the screen as it is and I am docking my wizard navigation buttons in a panel that is itself docked to the bottom of the form panel.  I will have to double check to see if my validation message label is forcing the control to a minimum size that is greater that the device resolution

Comment: There's a great commercial component called Orientation Aware Control that leverages the localization features of WinForms to let you specify the UI layout of different devices at design time without changing the code behind them. See [Orientation Aware Control](http://www1.orientationaware.net/features.html#). But you can't escape identifying the viewable sizes on each device.
You could try removing the control anchors so the controls float to the center of the screen, but that is pretty restrictive.